# How does android.graphics.CornerPathEffect work?

Tags: java, android, svg, graphics

I want to convert android.graphics.Path to svg path data. I made a script which works pretty well, but the lines aren't as smooth as original.

[Before convertion (android.graphics.Path drawn on Canvas object)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgdFi.jpg)

[After convertion (Generated .svg file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRrqc.png)

**How can I fix this?**

Here is my code:

```
 private String createPathData(android.graphics.Path path){
    
    List<PointF> points = getPoints(path);

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("M ")
            .append((int) points.get(0).x)
            .append(" ")
            .append((int) points.get(0).y)
            .append(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 4; i += 4) {

        float lastX = (int) points.get(i).x;
        float lastY = (int) points.get(i).y;

        float x = (int) points.get(i + 4).x;
        float y = (int) points.get(i + 4).y;

        //Creates bezier curve

        stringBuilder.append("C ");

        stringBuilder
                .append((int) x).append(" ").append((int) y).append(" ") //start point
                //Here is the problem.
                //There I should include CornerPathEffect in the formula, but don't know how.
                .append((int) (lastX + x) / 2).append(" ").append((int) (lastY + y) / 2).append(" ") //control point
                .append((int) lastX).append(" ").append((int) lastY).append(" "); //end point
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

and this is getPoints() method:

```
public static List<PointF> getPoints(Path path){
    PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
    List<PointF> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pathMeasure.getLength(); i+=4) {
        float[] coordinates = new float[]{0, 0};
        pathMeasure.getPosTan(i, coordinates, null);
        res.add(new PointF(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Then I insert the results into `d` attribute in svg `<path>` and I get something like this:

```
<path d="M 200 184 C 184 185 192 184 200 184 C 170 193 177 189 184 185 C 158 203 164 198 (...)/>
```

here is the full svg i generate: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_CF0SubXJFMsjVOYJHB5Chg6dEt3o2S/view?usp=sharing)

and this is how I draw the original:

```
//Creating a path

smartOnTouchEventListener.setOnTouchEventListener(new STouchListener.OnTouchEvent() {
        @Override
        public void onTouchStarted(int fingers, PointF[] points) {
            /*
             * Line is new. Starts line.
             */
            currentPath.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
            lastX = points[0].x;
            lastY = points[0].y;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMove(int fingers, PointF[] points) {

            //User draggs his finger and creates the path.
            float dx = Math.abs(points[0].x - lastX);
            float dy = Math.abs(points[0].y - lastY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                currentPath.quadTo(lastX, lastY, (points[0].x + lastX) / 2, (points[0].y + lastY) / 2);
                lastX = translateX(points[0].x);
                lastY = translateY(points[0].y);
            }
            //Here I draw a path
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEnd(int fingers, PointF[] points) {

            /*
            User ends new line.
             */
            //Here I save the path
            ...
            currentPath.reset();
            
        }
    });

//Drawing a path
Paint pen = new Paint();
pen.setAntiAlias(true);
pen.setColor(getPenColor());
pen.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
pen.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
pen.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
pen.setDither(true);

//I think this is the reason of difference between the original and generated one, 
//but can't find a source code of android.graphics.CornerPathEffect
pen.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));

pen.setStrokeWidth(getPenSize());
pen.setXfermode(getPenMode()));
pen.setAlpha(getPenAlpha());

canvas.drawPath(path, pen);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most of the methods in android Canvas are just wrappers around Skia classes.  You can find the Skia source code here. https://github.com/google/skia/blob/master/src/effects/SkCornerPathEffect.cpp

Comment: However, since your SVG paths appear to be more-or-less straight paths, with no corners, I have my doubts that CornerPathEffect is your problem.  Can you post the android code for your path, and the SVG you generate?  Also, what dows the methode `getPoints()` do?

Comment: Your bezier curve generating code is more likely the culprit.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thank you so much for the url, it's probably what I was looking for! I've edited my question and added what you wanted. And maybe I've not write too clearly. I don't think that `CornerPathEffect` works wrong, but it is why the original path is more smooth than generated one. I don't know how to change my code and include the `CornerPathEffect` in my formula.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem with your original code is how you are reconstructing the path.
I'm not sure why you are using a bezier curve here:

```
stringBuilder.append("C ");
stringBuilder
   .append((int) x).append(" ").append((int) y).append(" ") //start point
   .append((int) (lastX + x) / 2).append(" ").append((int) (lastY + y) / 2).append(" ")
   .append((int) lastX).append(" ").append((int) lastY).append(" "); //end point
```

You are mixing up your control points.  The three points in a bezier curve (C) path command are:

```
C <first control point> <second control point> <end point>
```

But you seem to be doing:

```
C <end point> <halfway point> <start point>
```

Which would result in a very messy line, I would expect.  You would be better off just drawing a straight line segment.

```
stringBuilder.append("L ");
stringBuilder.append((int) x).append(" ").append((int) y).append(" ")
```

---

BTW, you are making the same mistake when you are generating the original path.  The parameters are backwards.

```
currentPath.quadTo(lastX, lastY, (points[0].x + lastX) / 2, (points[0].y + lastY) / 2);
```

should be:

```
currentPath.quadTo((points[0].x + lastX) / 2, (points[0].y + lastY) / 2, points[0].x, points[0].y);
```

But this will just create a straight line segment also.  That's because your control point is just set to the halfway point.  So it is the same as doing:

```
currentPath.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
```

---

But why try to recreate the path afterwards anyway?  Why not just generate the SVG path at the same time as the original path?

```
smartOnTouchEventListener.setOnTouchEventListener(new STouchListener.OnTouchEvent() {
        @Override
        public void onTouchStarted(int fingers, PointF[] points) {
            /*
             * Line is new. Starts line.
             */
            currentPath.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
            currentSVG += "M " + points[0].x + " " + points[0].y + " ";
            lastX = points[0].x;
            lastY = points[0].y;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMove(int fingers, PointF[] points) {

            //User draggs his finger and creates the path.
            float dx = Math.abs(points[0].x - lastX);
            float dy = Math.abs(points[0].y - lastY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                currentPath.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
                currentSVG += "L " + points[0].x + " " + points[0].y + " ";
                lastX = translateX(points[0].x);
                lastY = translateY(points[0].y);
            }
            //Here I draw a path
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEnd(int fingers, PointF[] points) {

            /*
            User ends new line.
             */
            //Here I save the path
            ...
            currentPath.reset();
            
        }
    });
```

---

As for your PathEffect...  you should not need it.  I suspect you added it to try and smooth out the path.  Fixing your parameter order, or switching to straight line segments may fix that problem anyway.

Comment: Okey, I've tested your solutions and yes, the generated svg looks so much better with straight lines, but it is still not as smooth as the original. I also tried drawing path on my drawing view with both  bezier and straight lines and I don't know exactly why, but my solution with the mistake gives better results than straight lines... It's pretty weird... I'll change curves to straight lines in my svg, and maybe in the future I will try to find a better solution. Thank you so much for help!